# Tool for removing all the loops in C code

Tags: c, loops, goto

Is there any tool available for converting a C code with loops (while , do-while, for) to a C code with goto statements instead of the looping statements?

I tried Clang. I changed the code to the IR and converted it back , but the code totally different (more lines, following the SSA format, ..) though logically meaning the same.

It would be better if the resultant code looks more alike the original source code. If not, I would like to know about the different other options available.

Comment: No self-respecting developer would ever write such a program.

Comment: Why would one want such a horrible contraption?

Comment: In order to write one, one would likely use such a loop...

Comment: Why? Are you just trying to pull a prank on somebody? ;)

Comment: If you're doing this out of some deluded idea that you can optimize better than a compiler, stop right now.  The compiler does use branches under the hood anyway, so this will, if anything, make your code slower.

Comment: @Nate: I am trying to convert each line of code to be single operational. Hence I am trying to arrive at it. @GCATNM: If the situation calls for it

Comment: @Paul: I am trying to do some static analysis on the code.

Comment: Isn't this called a "disassembler"?  That's how most people try to manually inspect code in the fashion you are describing.

Comment: It would make more sense to perform loop unrolling, rather than just substitution of keywords.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a compiler. Not only will it turn all those neat and orderly loop constructs in your code into jump instructions, but it lets the original code remain totally unchanged and easy to maintain.

Special added bonus: compilers have tricks for speeding up your code, so it will run even faster than if you had just naively converted your C to assembler.
</snark>